# How do I answer the question "Who wants to read this?"?

Tags: spoken-english

When my teacher asks Who wants to read this? How do I reply?

> Me

or

> I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are making a complete sentence with a subject and verb, use

> I do!

If you are just producing a single word then use

> me!

Which you can understand as short for "The person who wants to read is me."

Using one word is perfectly correct way to respond, a complete sentence is not required